# how to pause or stop or quit MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql

I have a page of mysql languages in workbench. Sometimes I want to run a particular line. However, when I accidentally do not select a line and run execute, it starts to run from line 1 onward. This will mess up tables, database and so on that precede the line 1.

I try to put "quit" or "exit" as in the first line but I have the following error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exit' at line 1
```

Thank you Experts

Comment: It is executed as a script, so, anything before the syntax error (unless u have a transaction) was properly executed... Which is what you want, If I understand your need

Comment: You should either learn to use that tool more effectively, being very careful about what you run, or find another tool that works better. You need to be extremely careful when using a production database. Accidentally running commands is a risk you need to learn to avoid.

Comment: For scripts I "hang out in", I block my code with comments. Rem them out. At least the data changing ones. The inquisitive selects not so much so. If I have a standalone production script it is elsewhere. I don't  "hang out" in them.